# How do I get GTA:San Andreas and Most Wanted to work in WINE?

Tags: wine

I have installed versions of San Andreas and Most Wanted which I used to just click and play in Windows but in Ubuntu they don't seem to work.

I have installed Wine 1.3 but while using San Andreas all I get is black and white screens which flash. To try to fix the problem I gave this command in terminal:
`sudo apt-get remove --purge wine wine1.3` .

Now I suppose it is installing wine 1.2.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time, thanks, makes the site more searchable, and thus more useful.

Answer (score 2):

The [Wine application database](http://appdb.winehq.org/) contains information on the support status of very many Windows applications and games under different versions of Wine. When there are special instructions to follow for a specific application, they can usually be found there.

A different option is to install [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/), which automates these special steps and tries to use the best Wine version for each application. Both GTA games you mentioned appear to be supported by PlayOnLinux, which you can install by clicking [this link](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/playonlinux).